# Why can we by the division algorithm factorise $f(x)=q(x)(x^2+1)+(a+bx)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, field-theory

Why can we by the division algorithm factorise $f(x)=q(x)(x^2+1)+(a+bx)$, what is the proof that this is the case?

It was just assumed to be the case when they were showing that $\Bbb R[x]/\langle x^2+1\rangle\cong \Bbb C$.

Moreover, say we divide any polynomial $f(x)$ of degree $n$ by a polynomial, $g(x)$ of degree $a$, do we get $f(x)=q(x)g(x)+r(x)$ where $r(x)$ is a polynomial of degree $ a\gt$

Sorry if it's a dumb question

Comment: $x^2+1$ is a degree 2 polynomial. So the remainder $r$ in $f=q*(x^2+1)+r$ will have degree deg$(r)<$ deg$($x^2+1)=2$. The general form of r is thus a degree 1 polynomial, so $r=a+bx$ for some $a$ and $b$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because for any field $F$, the ring $F[x]$ is a Euclidean domain. However, in this case, it can be proved directly:

Claim: if $\text{deg}(f) \in \Bbb R[x] \geq 2$, then we can write:

$f(x) = q(x)(x^2 + 1) + r(x)$, where either $r(x) = 0$, or $\text{deg}(r) < 2$, for some $q(x) \in \Bbb R[x]$.

The proof is by induction on $n = \text{deg}(f)$.

Base case: $n = 2$.

We can write $f(x) = ax^2 + bx + c$, and we have $a \neq 0$, since $f$ is of degree $2$.

Now if we set $q(x) = a$ (a constant polynomial), we have:

$f(x) = a(x^2 + 1) + bx + (c - a)$, and we can take $r(x) = bx + (c-a)$, which is either of degree $1$ (if $b \neq 0$), degree $0$ (if $b = 0$ and $c \neq a$), or equal to $0$ (if $b = 0$ and $c = a$).

Induction hypothesis: so now we assume that our claim holds whenever $f$ is of degree $2 \leq k < n$.

Suppose $\text{deg}(f) = n$. So:

$f(x) = a_nx^n + \cdots + a_2x^2 + a_1x + a_0$, where $a_n \neq 0$.

Now $f(x) = a_nx^{n-2}(x^2 + 1) + a_{n-1}x^{n-1} + (a_{n-2} - a_n)x^{n-2} + \cdots + a_2x^2 + a_1x + a_0$.

So if we take $q_1(x) = a_nx^{n-2}$, we can take:

$r_1(x) =  a_{n-1}x^{n-1} + (a_{n-2} - a_n)x^{n-2} + \cdots + a_2x^2 + a_1x + a_0$.

If $\text{deg}(r_1) < 2$ or $r_1(x) = 0$, we have proven the claim for $n$ directly. Otherwise, we can apply our induction hypothesis to $r_1$, to obtain:

$r_1(x) = q_2(x^2 + 1) + r_2(x)$ where $\text{deg}(r_2) < 2$ or $r_2(x) = 0$.

Then $f(x) = (q_1(x) + q_2(x))(x^2 + 1) + r_2(x)$, and we are done.

Note that in the case that $\text{deg}(f) < 2$, or $f = 0$, we may simply take $q(x) = 0$, so our claim above actually holds for ANY $f(x) \in \Bbb R[x]$.

But if $\text{deg}(r) < 2$ or $r(x) = 0$, we can surely write:

$r(x) = ax + b$, for some $a,b \in \Bbb R$.

Comment: Thanks so much, this was very helpful!

Comment: Would you mind looking at my argument in the other answer for the general case, I am fairly sure it is alright, it took me a long time to think up

Answer (score 0):

To see some intuition into why the remainder has lower degree, lets consider polynomial long division:

$$g(x)\overset{q(x)}{\overline{\smash{)}f(x)}}$$

---

If $g(x)$ divides $f(x)$ with no remainder, it means that $f(x)=g(x)q(x)$, and in this case remainder is $0$.

---

Say that $g(x)\not| f(x)$

if $\deg(g(x))\gt \deg(f(x))$ then $f(x)=r(x)$ and $\deg(g(x))\gt r(x)$.

---

Say that $g(x)\not|f(x)$ and $\deg(g(x))\lt \deg(f(x))$

Then if $f(x)$ is of degree $n$ it has leading term $ax^n$ and if $g(x)$ is of degree $m\lt n$, then $bx^m$ is the leading term of $g(x)$. Let's divide $\frac{g(x)}{b}$ to make it monic. Then the leading term of $q(x)$ is $ax^{n-m}$. This means that all of the leading term of $f(x)$ is made up by leading terms in the product $g(x)q(x)$'s:

$x^m\times ax^{n-m}=ax^n$, or after considering we reduced $g(x)$ to a monic, we get $ bx^m\times \frac{a}{b}x^{n-m}=ax^n$

So then none of $ax^n$ is made up in the remainder, and the remainder surely cannot have a degree greater than $f(x)$, so then $\deg(r(x))\not\geq \deg(f(x))$ and hence  $\deg(r(x))\lt \deg(g(x)q(x))=\deg(f(x))$